# Pycharm Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymoo.algorithms'; 'pymoo' is not a package

Tags: python, pycharm, pymoo

I've tried to run the example code from pymoo for NSGA2 in PyCharm.

```
from pymoo.algorithms.moo.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.factory import get_problem
from pymoo.optimize import minimize
from pymoo.visualization.scatter import Scatter

problem = get_problem("zdt1")

algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=100)

res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               ('n_gen', 200),
               seed=1,
               verbose=False)
plot = Scatter()
plot.add(problem.pareto_front(), plot_type="line", color="black", alpha=0.7)
plot.add(res.F, facecolor="none", edgecolor="red")
plot.show()
```

It gives me always this Error:

```
/Users/myname/opt/miniconda3/envs/namename/bin/python /Users/myname/PycharmProjects/name/namename/pymoo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/name/namename/pymoo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pymoo.algorithms.moo.nsga2 import NSGA2
  File "/Users/mynae/PycharmProjects/name/namename/pymoo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pymoo.algorithms.moo.nsga2 import NSGA2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymoo.algorithms'; 'pymoo' is not a package
```

I have already downloaded pymoo under the preferences and when I try to download pymoo in the terminal again it says that all packages are already installed.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your file, for example to `pymoo_test.py` (or something else entirely) and it should work.

Your stack trace tells me that your file is called `pymoo.py`:

```
File "/Users/mynae/PycharmProjects/name/namename/pymoo.py", line 1, in <module>
```

The file name is what is causing your problem. What's happening is that the imports are being tried to be imported from your `pymoo.py` file due to the name and you trying to import from `pymoo.<...>` in the same file.